# Vertica - Count the number of TRUE values from multiple columns

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a table with a primary key and a multiple markers which can be set to 1 or 0.

This is how the table looks like:

[image]

My final table has 108 of those m-values.

I want to know how many 1's each row has. For e.g.

```
ID  | Sum_True
123 | 1
253 | 3
548 | 1
112 | 3
256 | 3
363 | 1
```

Comment: 108 m columns?!? Seems like a poor table design.

Comment: I gave them m names for simplicity but they are actually diseases markers. So, they are all different

Comment: Speaking SQL, I'd consider 1 row per patient and disease (value 1). I.e. columns id and disease.

Comment: Its a row level logic, while Vertica columnar db. You can create an UDF to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Should be a simple addition of column

```
select id, m1+m2+m3+m4+m5 as sum_true
from my_table
```

For the 108 columns, you could dynamically build the SQL code string e. using the schema information eg. for columns https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/SystemTables/CATALOG/COLUMNS.htm

Comment: Should I add them 108 time? Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: you could build the query dinamically server side,   building  dinamically the related  sql string ...  if the column name have the same pattern..

Comment: They don't follow the same pattern. I guess I'll have to add them one by one

Comment: eg you could select the table column https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/SystemTables/CATALOG/COLUMNS.htm on the result of this build your query  string ..

Answer (score 1):

I did a template of [UDSFs](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ExtendingVertica/UDx/ScalarFunctions/ScalarFunctions.htm%3FTocPath%3DExtending%2520Vertica%7CDeveloping%2520User-Defined%2520Extensions%2520(UDxs)%7CScalar%2520Functions%2520(UDSFs)%7C_____0) on C++ for you, source code you can find [here](https://github.com/sKwa/vertica/blob/master/UDx/RowSumUDSFs.cpp). Tested on `Vertica Analytic Database v8.1.1-10`.

I can improve code if you will define your requirements better(programming language[C++/Java/Python], Vertica version, function signature, etc).

### Example

**Data:**

```
dbadmin=> select * from eldj;
 id  | m01 | m02 | m03 | m04 | m05
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
 112 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   1 |   1
 123 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   0 |   0
 253 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   1 |   1
 256 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0
 363 |   0 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0
 548 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   1
(6 rows)
```

**Usage:**

```
dbadmin=> select id, rowsum(*) - id as 'SUM_TRUE' from eldj;
 id  | SUM_TRUE
-----+----------
 112 |        3
 123 |        1
 253 |        4
 256 |        2
 363 |        1
 548 |        1
(6 rows)
```

**Compile:**

Download src code to `/tmp` folder.

```
g++ -D HAVE_LONG_INT_64 -I /opt/vertica/sdk/include \
    -Wall -shared -Wno-unused-value -fPIC \
    -o /tmp/RowSumUDSFs.so /tmp/RowSumUDSFs.cpp /opt/vertica/sdk/include/Vertica.cpp
```

**Install:**

```
DROP LIBRARY IF EXISTS  RowSumUDSFs CASCADE;
CREATE OR REPLACE LIBRARY RowSumUDSFs AS '/tmp/RowSumUDSFs.so';
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rowsum AS LANGUAGE 'C++' NAME 'RowSumFactory' LIBRARY RowSumUDSFs;
```

### UPDATE

I added to function parameter `exclude` in case of column isn't `int` data type.

**Example:**

```
daniel=> select * from eldj ;
 col  | m01 | m02 | m03 | m04 | m05
------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
 key1 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   0 |   0
 key2 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   1 |   1
 key3 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   1
 key4 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   1 |   1
 key5 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0
 key6 |   0 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0
(6 rows)

daniel=> select col, rowsum(* using parameters exclude='col') as 'SUM_TRUE' from eldj;
 col  | SUM_TRUE
------+----------
 key1 |        1
 key2 |        4
 key3 |        1
 key4 |        3
 key5 |        2
 key6 |        1
(6 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select col,m01+m02+m03+m04+m05 as SUM_TRUE from eldj
```